# Simplest web3 SendSignedTransaction not working for 10th nonce?

Tags: web3js

The most basic code to start a transaction is not working for me. after the 9th transaction. How can this be. I have the following .js file and I start it in CMD with Node C:/Programs/code_snippets/create-transaction.js

Started it perfectly fine 9 times, then the 10th in didn't work. Repeated this 2x, because I thought I messed up code without remembering. Any advice?

I don't get any error, it just stays doing nothing after receiving 
Tx Hex: f86f10852e90edd000830c350094b29d0bde21ff7f1a89ebed0d9c40ca9f71119d7c87038d7ea4c68000834869212aa0ed69e3115bce1c0e06d6695027c109dfa0c9748c669175ccf214a0fe62664fa6a045de9493ebe5cce95e65e46640652d312f635e8d42ad3c2742688bb11ffaa999

```
   // Add the web3 node module
var Web3 = require('web3');

// Show web3 where it needs to look for the Ethereum node.
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/Whm5Ks3VGzJMBGHh4MEx'));

// An extra module is required for this, use npm to install before running
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

// Used to sign the transaction. Obviously you SHOULD better secure this than just plain text
var privateKey = new Buffer('265f303edd16be057608a0810414c2889c24e7ce8e9e4a88ae5b8a561c26935a', 'hex');

 // The receiving address of the transaction
var receivingAddr = ('0x29307EE93F49E9eB1425e40C9119b9Cb6e39d9B5');

// Value to be sent, converted to wei and then into a hex value
var txValue = web3.utils.numberToHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether'));

var noncePromise = web3.eth.getTransactionCount('0x24003FbB79cfA541eE32C59ef3A7424541f4AA01', 'pending');
var balancePromise = web3.eth.getBalance('0xED54EbBC73C7fb8B6607547b7541D8799708D93B');
var gasPricePromise = web3.eth.getGasPrice();
//var PendingTransactionFromBlock = web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock('pending', 2)
var BlockPromise = web3.eth.getBlock('pending', false);



var allPromises = Promise.all([
    noncePromise,
    balancePromise,
    gasPricePromise,
    BlockPromise

]);

 // This function is ONLY called once ALL promises are fulfilled
    var sendPromise = allPromises.then(function(results) {
    var nonce = results[0];
    var balance = results[1];
    var gasPrice = results[2];
    var Block = results[3];


 var run = true;
    var i = 0;
    var numberBlockTransactionHashes = Block.transactions.length;
    var TransactionDataPromise = [];
    TransactionDataPromise.push(web3.eth.getTransaction(Block.transactions[i]));
    console.log("numberBlockTransactionHashes: " + numberBlockTransactionHashes);
/* while (run) {

    TransactionDataPromise.push(web3.eth.getTransaction(Block.transactions[i]));

    if (i == numberBlockTransactionHashes)
    {
        run = false;
        continue; // jump to top
    }

    i++
}     */


// Data to be sent in transaction, converted into a hex value. Normal tx's do not need this and use '0x' as default, but who wants to be normal?
var txData = web3.utils.asciiToHex('hi'); 

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x' + nonce, // Nonce is the times the address has transacted, should always be higher than the last nonce 0x0#
 gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000), 
gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(200000000000), 
 to: receivingAddr, // The receiving address of this transaction
  value: txValue, // The value we are sending '0x16345785d8a0000' which is 0.1 Ether
  data: txData // The data to be sent with transaction, '0x6f6820686169206d61726b' or 'oh hai mark' 
}

console.log(rawTx); // This is used for testing to see if the rawTx was formmated created properly, comment out the code below to use.


var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(privateKey); // Here we sign the transaction with the private key

var serializedTx = tx.serialize(); // Clean things up a bit

console.log("Tx Hex" + serializedTx.toString('hex')); // Log the resulting raw transaction hex for debugging if it fails to send

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')) // Broadcast the transaction to the network
.on('receipt', console.log); // When a receipt is issued, log it to the console

});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the 10th nonce and not the 11th? I think the issue is `'0x' + nonce`. When the nonce is 10, that will result in `"0x10"`, which means 16. If I'm right, just using `nonce` instead of `'0x' + nonce` should work.

Comment: Cheers. Please submit it as an answer so I can click on resolved! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue should occur when the nonce is 10 (the *eleventh* nonce, not the tenth).

The problem is `'0x' + nonce`. When the nonce is 10, that will result in `"0x10"`, which means 16. Just using `nonce` instead of `'0x' + nonce` should resolve the issue.